# How to hide lock image from row 0 in UICollectionView when Scrolling swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, it is working perfect. I added lock image on all row except row 0. When ViewController is loaded,it is working fine but when i scroll it horizontally, it is showing lock image on row 0. what i am doing wrong? Thanks in advace.

Here is my code:-

```
var imageView1 = UIImageView()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = tittle[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named : image[indexPath.row] )

    imageView1  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x :cell.frame.size.width / 2 - 30 ,y : 40, width : 30, height : 30));

    imageView1.image = UIImage(named: "lock.png")
    imageView1.image =  imageView1.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView1.tintColor = UIColor.white

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        imageView1.isHidden = true
        imageView1.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        cell.imageView.addSubview(imageView1)
        if (RemoteModel.sharedInstanceRemoteModel.purchased){
            imageView1.isHidden = true
        } else {
            imageView1.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: Added code buddy.

Comment: why you add Subview UIImageView inside UIImageView?

Comment: actually i have images in all row, thats why i'm adding subview if lock icon image on imageview.

Comment: see answer put your imageview1 code inside else and add imageview inside cell try may be its work.

Comment: you create imageview like cell.imageView then hide show its working fine i will check this approach is not working because its add subview everytime so they add overlay UIImageview.

Comment: So what you suggest best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using the custom collection view cell which is CollectionViewCell

So try adding that in your custom cell xib or story board prototype cell wherever you have designed it

and then connnect it to outlet

and after that try hiding/unhiding that image view according to the condition

And initially try keeping it hidden in xib or story board

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.label.text = tittle[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named : image[indexPath.row] )

    if (indexPath.item == 0)
    {
        cell.imageView1.isHidden = true
    }
    else
    {
        if (RemoteModel.sharedInstanceRemoteModel.purchased)
        {
            cell.imageView1.isHidden = true
        }
        else
        {
            cell.imageView1.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Yes it should but it's not working in your case so try another apporach

Comment: Thanks buddy, it is working now. I added small image, on image view from storyboard, than make initially hide it, than put the lock image image on it, it is working.

Comment: @ChetanLodhi Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the UIImageView `imageView1` in `cell.imageView` with this method cell.imageView.addSubview(imageView1)

If you are adding this directly into the cell you need to remove from its superview, because `imageView1` don't have the reference from the previous cell, we are use the cell reuse.
For Either you can go with the above solution or you need to add the lock image in for custom Cell and maintain the **hide/show** in:

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {`

Comment: Problem is coming when i'm scrolling. i also added  imageView1.removeFromSuperview() in if block. It does not work.

Comment: Did you tried with add an image in custom Cell create image object  like `cell.imageView` and 


`if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.lockImage.isHidden = true

    } else {
cell.lockImage.isHidden = false
}
`

Comment: Buddy it is hide when view is loaded first time, when i am scrolling, than on o location lock image is coming. this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me,  I added small image, on image view from storyboard, than make initially hide it, than put the lock image image on it, it is working.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = tittle[indexPath.row]

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named : image[indexPath.row] )

        imageView1  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x :cell.frame.size.width / 2 - 30 ,y : 40, width : 30, height : 30));

        cell.lockiconmindcultivation.isHidden = false
            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.image = UIImage(named: "lock.png")
            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.image =  cell.lockiconmindcultivation.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.tintColor = UIColor.white

        if (indexPath.row == 0){

            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.isHidden = true
            }

            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.isHidden = false
            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.image = UIImage(named: "lock.png")
            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.image =  cell.lockiconmindcultivation.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            cell.lockiconmindcultivation.tintColor = UIColor.white

            if (RemoteModel.sharedInstanceRemoteModel.purchased){
                cell.lockiconmindcultivation.isHidden = true
            }else{
                cell.lockiconmindcultivation.isHidden = false
            }
        }

        return cell
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding lock image view in your storyboard but if you want to add it from code, You should be adding lock image view in your `CollectionViewCell` and just hide/unhide it from `cellForItemAt`. I suppose your cell is designed in storyboard or nib.

```
class CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    var lockImageView: UIImageView?
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        lockImageView = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x :self.frame.size.width / 2 - 30 ,y : 40, width : 30, height : 30));
        lockImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "lock.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        lockImageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.contentView.addSubview(lockImageView!)
    }
}
```

And in `cellForItemAt` just hide/unhide.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = tittle[indexPath.row]
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named : image[indexPath.row] )

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.lockImageView.isHidden = true
    } else {
        if (RemoteModel.sharedInstanceRemoteModel.purchased){
            cell.lockImageView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            cell.lockImageView.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

It's not efficient to added views and remove within `cellForItemAt` method. And also you are not supposed to add views in `UIImageView`.